# Swift and Parse fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer while retrieving images from Parse and populating array

Tags: arrays, image, swift, parse-platform

Swift fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer while retrieving images from Parse and populating array

Hi there,
I have been trying for days now to get something to work, my first app that is trying to pull images out of a Parse database. I have successfully connected with Parse, can see data appearing there, including image uploads. The one image I have uploaded at the moment is a 90 Kb image of type PNG (so a very small file).

Now I’d like to show these images to the user, and let him take action on them, then be presented with the next one. To do this, I want to put the images into an array on the loading of the page. When I try to access this array (at element zero), I get an error fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer  which I read as “empty array”. I have tried various things, including starting a fresh Parse project, creating new users and uploading new Images in case something was wrong there.

From reading around, I think the problem might be because I am using a Find Objects In Background With Block wrapper to populate this array. So I am trying to access the array before the process or thread that is populating it is finished. I have tried to put this executing code into a dispatch_sync and similar, but that also didn’t work.

Can anyone suggest any ideas that might fix this?
Really grateful, I’m just unable to solve it as my current learning/knowledge point..

thanks
Patrick

```
import UIKit

class SwipetimeViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

     @IBOutlet var loginlabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var showImage: UIImageView!
var foodTypeDescriptions = [NSString]()
var foodTypeImages = [NSData]()


   func getImages () {
    var query = PFQuery(className:"FoodType")
    var foodType = PFObject(className: "FoodType")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (foodTypes, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        for foodType in foodTypes
        {
            if (foodType["Title"] != nil && foodType["imageFile"] != nil)
            {

                self.foodTypeDescriptions.append(foodType["Title"] as     NSString)
                self.foodTypeImages.append(foodType["imageFile"] as NSData)
            }
        }
})
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Parse.setApplicationId(“XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX”, clientKey:   “YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY)

    var userImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,     self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))
    userImage.image = UIImage(data: self.foodTypeImages[0])
    userImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    self.view.addSubview(userImage)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what showImage is. Are you trying to show a userImage?

Comment: your code speaks to the intent of showing a single userImages but you are querying for food images. I would revisit your logic